# Python virtual env still requires Python to be installed in order to run scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I am trying to run my Python application using Python 3 virtual env but without Python 3 installed, my scripts don't run. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How did you set up virtualenv without python?

Answer (score 0):

`venv` doesn't create redistributable standalone applications, it creates virtual environments.

If you want a standalone application, you need to use some tool to build it—`py2exe`, `PyInstaller`, `py2app`, `cx_Freeze`, etc. These tools have all kinds of logic to do things like bundle up just enough of Python itself, its stdlib, your third-party modules, C libraries any of the above depend on, etc., and organize everything in such a way that it just works on any machine of a given platform.